# SonarScanner Job issue in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

- SonarQube Docker image Community edition 8.7.0
- Sonar Scanner latest image

I have setup sonarqube in a docker container. After adding the sonar-check stage in Gitlab CI, the scanner is not executing the stage properly. Gitlab Runner is running on the docker environment. Dind Service is enabled. Runner is running in privileged mode.

Following error is being thrown:

/bin/bash: line 118: docker: command not found

Steps to reproduce:

1. Setup ur project on sonarqube.
2. Configure Analysis with Gitlab CI
3. Build Technology Other
4. Configure sonar-project.properties file
5. Add other environment variables
   Copy gitlab configuration from sonarqube, paste it in .gitlab-ci.yml file.

My Gitlab job:

```
sonarqube-check:
  image: 
    name: sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
    SONAR_HOST_URL: ${SONAR_HOST_URL}
    SONAR_TOKEN: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script: 
    - sonar-scanner
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - master # or the name of your main branch
```